# Error al enviar imagen a pinterest por url usando Token

Tags: api

Hola amigos intento enviar una imagen a pinterest  de la siguiente manera:

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?access_token=******&fields=id%2Ccreator&link=https://localhost/&image_url=http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-cP9MUDC3OJ0/W8LoDjVkavI/AAAAAAAAL9o/qhe9uf069AgvIj1QHXpcpmOlmLxsYmn6wCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/294315_349074945197846_37345677_n-745549.jpg&board=chicas/chicas-malas&note=SAVE
```

según la información que suministra su pagina [Pinterest Api](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/?). El problema es que siempre me muestra el siguiente error:

```
{
  "message": "405: Method Not Allowed", 
  "type": "http"
}
```

y no logro descubrir cual es el error . 
Espero me puedan dar alguna idea o información

Comment: ¿Cómo estás realizando la petición y de qué tipo es? Leyendo la documentación en tu caso sería de tipo `POST`.

Comment: Como dice @AngelOropeza, el error es autoexplicativo. El servidor te está diciendo que el método http que usas (GET) es inválido para la operación que intentas usar. Por lo tanto, es posible que debas usar una petición POST.

Comment: Bien entiendo y gracias por la explicacion me pregunto. Si puedes darme un ejemplo de como tiene que quedar la url

Comment: Para darte una respuesta más específica necesitamos conocer con que lenguaje de programación estás trabajando o si estás utilizando algún cliente como *Postman* para realizar las peticiones a la API de Pinterest.

Comment: Yo octengo el token y lo que busco es solo enviar la imagen por url

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions Podrias editar tu pregunta y colocar el codigo donde realizas esta llamada a pinterest, y especificar que lenguaje utilizas? Tal y como dice AngelOropeza, es necesario saber esto para poder ayudarte.

Comment: E probado el método post y da el siguiente error {"status": "failure", "message": "API method not found.", "code": 11, "data": null}